# Decoding binary data from serial port

Tags: c++, raspberry-pi, serial-port, binary-data

I am trying communicate with a Simplebgc board via serial on my Raspberry Pi.  I am writing commands to the board which seems to be working but I need help decoding the binary response. Why am I getting 23 byes when the guide seems to add to 18?  I am new to both C and binary.

[image]

```
void sendCommand() {
    int fd;

    if ((fd = serialOpen ("/dev/ttyS0", 115200)) < 0) {
        //fprintf (stderr, "Unable to open serial device: %s\n", strerror (errno));
        cout<<"Unable to open serial device"<<endl;
        return;
    }

    unsigned char motor_on[6] = {0x3E, 0x4D, 0x01, 0x4E,0x01, 0x01}; //MOTOR ON
    unsigned char motor_off[6] = {0x3E, 0x6D, 0x01, 0x6E,0x01, 0x01};  //MOTOR OFF
    unsigned char board_info[6] = {0x3E, 0x56, 0x01, 0x57, 0x01, 0x01};  //BOARD_INFO

    serialFlush(fd);

    // Send command to grab board info
    write(fd, board_info, 6);
    sleep(2);

    // Read board response and print it
    char c;
    int counter = 0;
    while (read(fd, &c, 1) == 1) {
        //putchar(c);  // print out char    
        printf("%d ",c);
        counter++;
    }
    cout<<"\ncounter="<<counter<<endl;
    sleep(5);


}

int main() {
    sendCommand();
    return 0;
}
```

output:

> pi@raspberrypi:~/myPrograms/SerialGPIOExamples/c++/SBGC_board $
>   ./serialSBGCTest 
>   62 86 18 104 30 70 10 0 27 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 0 137 counter=23

Comment: Your debug output is absolutely useless. You are printing the long line of digits, but you have no idea what was the number you received from the board. For example, `628` - did you receive 6, followed by 28, 62 followed by 8 or 6 followed by 2 followed by 8?

Comment: What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: Updated my question.  Should %d print out the decimal digits correctly as specified in their manual?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The response is a message which has a header:

> Message format
>   Each command consists of the header and the body, both with checksum. Commands with the wrong header
>   or body checksum, or with the body size that differs from expected, should be ignored. Parser should scan
>   incoming datastream for the next start character and try to restore synchronization from it.

```
Header:
    Start Character    1u
    Command ID         1u
    Payload Size       1u
    Header Checksum    1u
Body
    18 bytes as defined by you.
    Body Checksum      1u
```

This gives you 23 bytes. 4 Bytes header. Body. 1 byte body checksum.

Comment: that makes sense now.  if a value is 2u for example FIRMWARE_VER would I need to do bit shifting cause it seems like its wrong.